# Does the order of Portal Shields matter?

Tags: ingress

As [Ingress Field Guide](http://ingressfieldguide.com/content/mission-items)(along with many other Ingress game guides) states that each portal shield placed after the first one will have diminished effect.

> **Portal Shield:**
>
> A type of MOD that can be installed on a Portal to increase its defense against attacks. You can deploy up to 4 shields per portal, but each shield has diminished effect after the first one.

What I wonder is, ordering of the shields after the first one is differed or not. I mean, Placing

```
VR, R, C, C *
```

and

```
VR, C, C, R *
```

are differed in effect?

---

```
* VR: Very Rare, 
  R: Rare, 
  C: Common
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A single Portal shield makes attacks 6% / 8% / 10% less effective. So if an attack without shields does 100% damage, with one VR shield the damage is 90%, and with two VR shields it'd be 81% (0.9*0.9). So four VR shields would reduce damage to 66% (0.9^4).

The effect is "diminished" because if you would simply add up the protection values, you'd end up with 60%.

Thus, since multiplication is commutative, order doesn't matter.