# Shield destruction order

Tags: ingress

When multiple shields are deployed on a portal, does the order of deployment or slot position affect which one gets destroyed first? e.g. if a VR is placed before a C, would that have a higher chance to disintegrate earlier vs having the C placed first?

Note that [Does the order of Portal Shields matter?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/114469/does-the-order-of-portal-shields-matter) is a different question which asks about mitigation and not destruction order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Destruction of shields appears to be random.

Ref: https://plus.google.com/communities/115073414859905315934/s/shields%20destruction

Answer (score 1):

I have been playing for a while now (I'm lv 5 and both of my parents are lv 8s) and every time we "pop shields off" enemy portals or watch ours get "popped off" the order has appeared to be random. But, it could be being determined by a advanced formula we can not comprehend yet

Answer (score 0):

No, the order is random.

Every shield has different probability to be destroyed, however I am not sure if in rare occasions you could pop off more shields at once.

[What is the requirement to destroy shield?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/144936/what-is-the-requirement-to-destroy-shield/149703#149703)