# What is the requirement to destroy shield?

Tags: ingress

What is the requirement to destroy a shield? Does it depend on the buster level or not? Are there any methods to easily destroy a portal shield?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### UPDATE

With the release of Ultra Strikes, new tactic to destroy portal's shields and other mods emerged.
If you stand right on the center of a portal and fire those, there is a very high chance to destroy the mods.

### UPDATE 2

New shield stickiness was introduced recently.

```
Shield Type         Old   New
Common shield       30    0
Rare shield         40    150000
Very Rare shield    60    450000
Very Rare "AXA"     70    800000
```

The tactics for destroying mods with ultrastrikes remain same, however it is now much harder to destroy the vrare+ shields.

### OLD ANSWER:

The mechanics behind destroying portal shields changed several times, but this is probably closest to the reality now.
If I recall correctly:

- Common shield: 10% chance
- Rare Shield: 8% chance
- Very Rare Shield: 6% chance

Also there is a difference between firing a L1 and L8 burster. The percentage might be influenced by the damage potencial of the weapon.

There used to be a special way to approach a portal from distance, destroying all it's shields without taking a damage and then dealing with unshielded portal. It utilized these factors:
 1. Portal hit range being around 60 meters.
 2. XMP L5 having range 90 meters.
 3. Fixed probability of destroying a shield.
 4. Firing from range between 70 - 90 meters.
But this now doesn't work as there are more factors influencing the destruction of a shield.